# MariaDB SUM returns wrong value on column type float

Tags: sql, mariadb

version: 5.5.53-MariaDB

I added this table to my MariaDB:

```
    CREATE TABLE `myTable` (   `key` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `val_float` float unsigned NOT NULL,   `val_bigint` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,   
   `val_int` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`key`));
```

and add an entry:

```
     INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (1, 9600240000, 9600240000, 4294967295);
```

and when I do sum on all columns

```
  select `key`,sum(`val_float`),sum(`val_bigint`),sum(`val_int`) from myTable;
```

result:

```
  +------+------------------+-------------------+----------------+
  | key  | sum(`val_float`) | sum(`val_bigint`) | sum(`val_int`) |
  +------+------------------+-------------------+----------------+
  |    1 |       9600239616 |        9600240000 |     4294967295 |
  +------+------------------+-------------------+----------------+
```

How do I get the wrong value in sum(`val_float`) (9600239616 instead of 9600240000)
and right values in the other columns

Thanks

Comment: Just read documentation: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/float/

Comment: This is correct behavior for the `float` data type.  If you want greater accuracy, use `numeric`/`decimal`.

Comment: @arvo by this documentation and I understand that maybe I add value to val_float bigger than what it can manage. but I try the same experiment with 877.8 value in val_float, and the result of sum is 877.7999877929688, but when I change the column type to double it works fine

Comment: Single precison float value has precision about 6,5 digits (not decimal places - documentation is not best). First 6 digits (rounded!) of 9600239616 are correct, 7th one almost too. For 877.8 again - first 6 digits (rounded!) of 877.7999877929688 are 877.800 - good enough. 7 digits (rounded!) are 877.8000 - correct. You should remember that floating point numbers are almost never exact; they can be used for scientific calculations (where some rounding and precision loss is expected), but never for storing and calculating with precise data types (money, quantities etc).

Comment: `SUM()` is not at fault.  `FLOAT` has limitations that you exceeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

9600240000 is a number which can't be represented exactly by `float` datatype (IEEE 754 32-bit single precision)

Simple example in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
  double double_value=9600240000;
  float float_value=9600240000;

  printf("float: %.14g double: %.14g\n", float_value, double_value);
}
```

When running it, it will produce the following output:

```
float: 9600239616 double: 9600240000
```

The binary representation of `9600240000` is `1000111100001110000000100110000000` (34-bits) - even if you would try to store this value in a 32-bit integer, it wouldn't work. If you need exact results, you should use the `DECIMAL` column type.